# win.reload showing showing blank white window in electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I need to reload my site/app after network re-connect. So, I'm using [win.reload](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winreload) after reconnect but after reloading it shows me a blank white screen

I have tried to re-create the window but it gives me the same output. Another question reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55969581/re-creation-of-main-window-shows-blank-page-in-electronjs) by me.

I found `window.location.href` is set to "chrome-error://chromewebdata/" after reload

This sample code from is main.js

```js
  let mainWindow = null;
  let offlineWindow = null;
  let loadingwindow = null;
  let mainWindowWidth = 1100;
  let mainWindowHeight = 650;

  var nativeApp = {
    appUrl: "https://google.com",
    connected: false
  }

  function createWindow () {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: false,
        preload: path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'preload.js')
      },
      minWidth: mainWindowWidth,
      width: mainWindowWidth,
      minHeight: mainWindowHeight,
      height: mainWindowHeight,
      show: false
    });

    createLoadingWindow();

    mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
      closeLoadingWindow();
      mainWindow.show();
    });

   mainWindow.setMenu(null);
   mainWindow.loadURL(nativeApp.appUrl);
   mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
 }

  function createLoadingWindow(){
    // codes to create the loading window
    // .....
  }

  function createOfflineWindow(){
    // codes to create the offline window
    //....
  }

  function checkAndConnect() {
    checkInternet(function (connected) {
      if (!connected) {
        if (!offlineWindow) { createOfflineWindow(); }
      } else {
        if (offlineWindow) {
          offlineWindow.close();
          mainWindow.reload();
        }
      }
      nativeApp.connected = connected;
    });
  }

  function checkInternet(callback) {
    if(navigator.onLine){
      return callback(true);
    }
    return callback(false);
  }
```

I need to reload my site/app after re-connection. Is there anything wrong in my code? or is it a bug by the electron?

Answer (score 1):

It's an old thread, but if someone comes across the same problem, you can fix it by adding the following in the main js file:

```js
function createMainWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    ...
  })

  // This code block is not related to the issue
  // I included it to demostrate how my app loads the index page
  if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    if (!process.env.IS_TEST) { 
      mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools() 
    }
  } 
  else {
    createProtocol('app')
    mainWindow.loadURL('app://./index.html')
  }

  // Create listener that will handle the white screen issue
  mainWindow.webContents.on('did-fail-load', () => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      // Load the index URL the same way you load it above
      mainWindow.loadURL('app://./index.html')
    }
  })
...
```