# How to get current URL from electron BrowserWindow object?

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to know the current URL of the [browser-window](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window). Is there any way to access window.location.href property of BrowserWindow or any other way to get it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the main process, use the window's webContents.[getURL()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsgeturl) method:

```
[...]
win = new BrowserWindow({ /* options */});
win.loadFile('index.html');
console.log (win.webContents.getURL();)
```

See: [How to get the url of the BrowserWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54185293/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-browserwindow/54187857#54187857)

Comment: This answer is acceptable. I've created this question to detect error URL( see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000178/win-reload-showing-showing-blank-white-window-in-electron) for more details). But `win.webContents.getURL()` showing the wrong URL to me